# Achievements in Django

Tags: python, django, achievements

I would like to add the achievements to my website. I would like them not to be assigned automatically, but that the user would add which achievements he made. I can't make a view for it.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Achievement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    grand = models.IntegerField(default=10, null=True)
    body = models.TextField()

class UserAchievement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_achievement = models.ManyToManyField(Achievement,  related_name='user_achievement')
    achievement_get = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

vievs.py

```
def achievement_view(request):
    achievement_list = Achievement.objects.order_by()
    return render(request, 'achievement/achievement.html', {
            'achievement_list' : achievement_list,
            })


def achievement_get(request, achievement_id):
        achievement_list = get_object_or_404(Achievement, pk=achievement_id)
        achi = get_object_or_404(Achievement, pk=achievement_id)
        try:
            selected_choice = achievement_list.score_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

        except (KeyError, Score.DoesNotExist):
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
                return render(request, 'achievement/adetail.html', {
                    'achievement_list': achievement_list,
                    'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
                    'thanks' : "Good",
                })
                

        else:
            a1 = get_object_or_404(Achievement, achievement_id)
            a1.save()
            a1.user_achievement.add(name=name)
            

            
            return render(request, 'achievement/adetail.html', {
                'achievement_list' : achievement_list,
                })
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'achievement'  # przestrzeń nazw aplikacji
urlpatterns = [
 # ex: /polls/
    path('achievement', views.achievement_view, name='achievement'),
    path('<int:achievement_id>/achievement', views.achievement_get, name='achievement_get'),
    ]
```

achievement.html

```
{% for achievement in achievement_list %}

    <li>{{ achievement.title }}</li>
    <li><fieldset><a href="/{{achievement_id}}/achievement/"> {{ achievement.title }} {{ achievement.grand }}</a></fieldset></li>

{% endfor %}
```

When I click on the link, the <int: achievement_id> doesn't work.

Comment: href="{% url 'achievement_get' achievement_id %}"

Comment: Message from the site: NoReverseMatch at /achievementachievement Reverse for 'achievement_get' not found. 'achievement_get' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Elsewhere, this link works: href="/{{achievement_id}}/achievement/"

Answer (score 1):

Try in your html template:

```
href="{% url 'achievement_get' achievement_id %}"
```

This will pass the achievement_id to your int:achievement_id in your url and call the function views.achievement_get.

Comment: Message from the site: NoReverseMatch at /achievementachievement
Reverse for 'achievement_get' not found. 'achievement_get' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Elsewhere, this link works: href="/{{achievement_id}}/achievement/"

Comment: Should be `{% url 'achievement:achievement_get' achievement_id %}` since `app_name` was specified